# How to find incomplete downloaded files of updated OS?

Tags: apt, updates

My internet connection was lost while I was updating my OS from 16.04 to 17.04 and the process stopped.There were 10-15 files remaining to be downloaded.

Now after realising that 17.04 is not a LTS version I don't wanna update my OS. But what about the downloaded files? Will they occupy any space in hard drive? Will they affect my current OS 16.04? Should I delete them? If yes than how can I find them and delete them?

Answer (score 1):

> Now after realising that 17.04 is not a LTS version I don't wanna update my OS...

LTS or not, you should ALWAYS update your OS! If you don't like non-LTS versions, don't install them. Updates are delivered to fix errors, so you should install them.

Just do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and if mentioned in the output of above:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Downloaded packages are kept in `/var/cache/apt` and partial downloaded packages in `partial` in that directory. You can delete the files in `/var/cache/apt`, but it will be downloaded again next time you update, and the content of partial will normally be deleted when packages are fully downloaded. To delete the contents of `/var/cache/apt/partial`, you can run

```
sudo apt clean
```

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get` stores all downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. the partially downloaded packages are in `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`. to remove these packages and free up the space they are holding, you can `sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archive`

or simply `apt-get clean` will remove all downloaded PPA archives from the aforementioned directory - thus freeing up the space